# swift "cannot subscript a value of type" error

Tags: swift

I'm trying to do this:

```
self.prepared[$0]
```

where prepared is an instance of `Dictionary<String, (String, Size)>`, and $0 is a `String`.

Any ideas anyone - I don't know why this can't be subscripted.

---

(Full error is this: `error: cannot subscript a value of type 'inout PreparedImageResponses' (aka 'inout Dictionary<String, ProductImageResponse>')`

where PreparedImageResponses is a typealias of `[String: (String, Size)]` and ProductImageResponse is a typealias of a tuple `(String, Size)` (Size is just a struct).

Comment: I cannot reproduce this, please provide a [mcve]

Comment: Annoyingly, any small examples I make in a playground are absolutely fine. I'm beginning to think this is a Swift compiler output error - I think that my error is somewhere else, and this is just a side-effect of it.

Comment: What I sometimes do in cases like this, is assign `$0` to a local variable, then see what Swift makes of it. Maybe `$0` isn't actually a `String`? Lame, I know, but the compiler errors don't always add up, I've found....